# How to change number format in TextView

Tags: java, android, xml

If I add a a long double number into EditText, for example `1500000000`,
the Textview is displaying the number as `1.5E8`. I dont want it to be displayed in this format, I want it to displayed as `150000000`. How could I change that?

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `DecimalFormat`  to format it.

```
        {
            double doubleA = 1500000000;
            DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            txtv_test.setText(decimalFormat.format(doubleA)); //show 1500000000
        }
        {
            double doubleA = 1500000000.123;
            DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            txtv_test.setText(decimalFormat.format(doubleA)); //show 1500000000.12
        }
        {
            double doubleA = 1500000000.1;
            DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            txtv_test.setText(decimalFormat.format(doubleA)); //show 1500000000.1
        }
        {
            double doubleA = 0.12;
            DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            txtv_test.setText(decimalFormat.format(doubleA)); //show 0.12
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `String.valueOf()` method, so you get a String representation of the big number. In your case, it will be as below:

```
textview.setText(String.valueOf(1500000000));
```